# After being returned by my factory service, data is displaying with visible HTML tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

My data is `json_endoded($data);` array, fetched by my factory service. It is then put in a Javascript variable, which is in turn used as a template. When finally brought to a page for display, it is output like this:

```
Some text here<br/><br/> And some link <a class="someclass" href="#">here</a>.
```

You get the idea. If I print_r or even see echoed json_endoded array (directly on the PHP page that Angularjs service is calling for data), such HTML tags are not visible, break is interpreted correctly - a new row is there, etc...

What can I use to fix this - I don't want to just strip all the tags - I need to preserve whatever links or similar stuff is there (these are posts from various social networks).

This is how the string in a variable is used as a template in MY DIRECTIVE:

```
angular.module('socialPosts.directives', [])

    .directive('timelinePost', function($compile){

        var timelineV2 = "<time class='cbp_tmtime'>\n\
                            <span>{{content.publishedDate}}</span>\n\
                            <span>{{content.publishedMonth}}</span>\n\
                         </time><i class='cbp_tmicon rounded-x hidden-xs'></i>\n\
                        <div class='cbp_tmlabel'>\n\
                            <h2>{{content.displayName}}</h2>\n\
                            <div class='row'>\n\
                                <div class='col-md-4'>\n\
                                    <a href='' target='_blank'><img class='img-responsive' src='{{content.imageSrc}}' alt='' /></a>\n\
                                    <div class='md-margin-bottom-20'></div>\n\
                                </div>\n\
                                <div class='col-md-8'>\n\
                                    <p>{{content.content}}</p>\n\
                                </div>\n\
                            </div>\n\
                        </div>";


        var getTemplate = function(type){
            var template = '';
            switch(type){
                case 'googleplus':
                    template = timelineV2;
                    break;
                case 'facebook':
                    template = timelineV2;
            }
            return template;
        };


        var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){

            scope.$watch('networkCalled', function(value){
                if(value){
                    element.html(getTemplate(value));
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            });
        };


        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true,
            link: linker,
            scope: {
                content: '=',
                networkCalled: '='
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I invite the user who left the comment some 10 mins after the question was published and recommended using ng-bind-html - to write is again as an answer. At first, i didn't apply it correctly so it didn't work. After thinking about it a bit, I managed to get it work and actually that was indeed what I needed! I want to give him some credit by marking his answer correct.

Comment: After you updated your question I was looking at your code and I had no idea how it would render anything at all, so I deleted the answer. Undeleted now. Glad it helped you after all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing something like this

```
<div>{{myVariable}}</div>
```

Then change it to something like this

```
<div ng-bind-html="myVariable"></div>
```

This will likely cause an error, which can be resolved using `ngSanitize` or `$sce` as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: That seems like a proper solution to the problem but I'm afraid I'm using it differently and I just tried to put ng-bind-html to the element (custom directive) but then nothing shows (yes, I added dependency on ngSanitize on my app). See the question again, I've update it with directive code.

Comment: Just to add this: If you look at my directive code, I put it on the paragraph that holds the {{content.content}}, like this: `<p ng-bind-html="content.content"></p>`. That did the trick and I thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'm new to Angularjs and help is always appreciated.